# How can I write to Perl filehandles that I stored in array?

Tags: perl, filehandle

I have a list of filenames. I have to create a file for each of those names, write lines to the various files (in no particular order), then close them.

How can I do that in perl? I envision something like the following code (which will not work in that form and give syntax errors):

```
my @names = qw(foo.txt bar.txt baz.txt);
my @handles;

foreach(@names){
  my $handle;
  open($handle, $_);
  push @handles, $handle; 
}

# according to input etc.:
print $handles[2] "wassup";
print $handles[0] "hello";
print $handles[1] "world";
print $handles[0] "...";

foreach(@handles){
  close $_;
}
```

How can I do this right?

Comment: I suspect this would be better done with references to file handles... but I'm not too keen on file handles in perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do it (untested, but I'm pretty sure it is good):

```
use IO::File;

# ...
my @handles = map { IO::File->new($_, 'w') } @names;

$handles[2]->print("wassup");
# ...
```

It's OO, it has a cleaner interface, and you don't need to worry about closing them, since it will die when the array goes out of scope.

Comment: die? perhaps you mean "do so".  But the example in the question does that too; nothing to do with IO::File.

Comment: By "die", I meant, the IO::File object would be DESTROYed, which I thought closed the filehandle, but apparently that is just garbage collection, so as long as they are lexically scoped they die anyway.

Comment: "-1" for "you don't need to worry about closing them". You always close whatever you open.

Answer (score 16):

The filehandle argument of `print` must be a bareword, a simple scalar, or a block.
So:

```
print { $handles[0] } ...
```

This is explained in [perldoc -f print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html).
The same restriction applies to [indirect object syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax) in general, as well as for determining when <> is a readline operation, not a glob operation.